# Will Tor remain effective after the reversal of the FCC's "Protecting the Privacy of Customers of Broadband and Other Telecommunications Services"

Tags: network-configuration

I was wondering if Tor will remain affective after this law is passed? 
https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/34

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Tor already provided protection from a snooping ISP, since it intends to protect from any single vantage point from being able to deanonymize Tor users.

Your ISP will see what it already has:

- You use Tor.
- When you use Tor.
- How long you use Tor for.
- How much (traffic/volume) you use Tor.

Comment: The policy that was eliminated was scheduled to take effect on 2017-12-04. So, I don't think much changed except that the ISPs got confirmation that selling your data is legal.